# Elegant, pythonic solution for forcing all keys and values to lower case in nested dictionaries of Unicode strings?

Tags: python

I'm curious how the Python Ninjas around here would do the following, elegantly and pythonically:

I've got a data structure that's a dict from unicode strings to dicts from unicode strings to unicode string lists. So:

```
>>> type(myDict)
<type 'dict'>
>>> type(myDict[u'myKey'])
<type 'dict'>
>>> type(myDict[u'myKey'][u'myKey2'])
<type 'list'>
>>> type(myDict[u'myKey'][u'myKey2'][0])
<type 'unicode'>
```

I want to go through and make every string in it lowercase, i.e. every key and every string in every list.

How would you do this?

Comment: -1 for not saying anything useful about your problem in the title

Comment: <red face> oops... sorry.  Got some good answers anyways, though. Thanks, all!

Comment: im sure it's obvious, but this only has a good solution if you are sure that there are no keys which are distinguished only by case.  e.g. if you have a 'myKey2' and a 'MyKey2' and a 'mykey2' in the original list...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Really simple way, though I'm not sure you'd call it Pythonic:

```
newDict = eval(repr(myDict).lower())
```

Saner way:

```
newDict = dict((k1.lower(),
                dict((k2.lower(),
                      [s.lower() for s in v2]) for k2, v2 in v1.iteritems()))
               for k1, v1 in myDict.iteritems())
```

Comment: I wouldn't actually _use_ the eval/repr approach, but +1 for something I'd never have thought of :-)

Answer (score 4):

A recursive variant:

```
def make_lowercase(obj):
    if hasattr(obj,'iteritems'):
        # dictionary
        ret = {}
        for k,v in obj.iteritems():
            ret[make_lowercase(k)] = make_lowercase(v)
        return ret
    elif isinstance(obj,basestring):
        # string
        return obj.lower()
    elif hasattr(obj,'__iter__'):
        # list (or the like)
        ret = []
        for item in obj:
            ret.append(make_lowercase(item))
        return ret
    else:
        # anything else
        return obj
```

Example:

```
>>> make_lowercase({'Foo': [{1: 'Baz', 'Bar': 2}]})
{'foo': [{1: 'baz', 'bar': 2}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for your example input:

```
>>> myDict = {'myKey': {'myKey2': [u'Abc']}}
>>> newDict = dict([
        (k1.lower(), dict([
            (k2.lower(), [x.lower() for x in myDict[k1][k2]])
                for k2 in myDict[k1].keys()
        ])) for k1 in myDict.keys()
    ])
>>> newDict
{'mykey': {'mykey2': [u'abc']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind modifying your input:

```
def make_lower(x):
    try:
        return x.lower()    # x is a string
    except AttributeError:
        # assume x is a dict of the appropriate form
        for key in x.keys():
            x[key.lower()] = make_lower(x[key])
            if key != key.lower():
                del x[key]

    return x

make_lower(myDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this late - as the question is tagged `Python`.
Hence answering with a solution for both `Python 2.x` and `Python 3.x`, and also handling the case of non-string keys i.e. The solution in the accepted answer will fail in case of numeric key.

**Python 2.x** - using dictionary comprehension

```
{k.lower() if isinstance(k, basestring) else k: v.lower() if isinstance(v, basestring) else v for k,v in yourDict.iteritems()}
```

**Demo**:

```
>>> yourDict = {"Domain":"WORKGROUP", "Name": "CA-LTP-JOHN", 111: 'OK', "Is_ADServer": 0, "Is_ConnectionBroker": 0, "Domain_Pingable": 0}
>>> {k.lower() if isinstance(k, basestring) else k: v.lower() if isinstance(v, basestring) else v for k,v in yourDict.iteritems()}
{'domain': 'workgroup', 'name': 'ca-ltp-john', 'is_adserver': 0, 'is_connectionbroker': 0, 111: 'ok', 'domain_pingable': 0}
```

---

**Python 3.x**

```
{k.lower() if isinstance(k, str) else k: v.lower() if isinstance(v, str) else v for k,v in yourDict.items()}
```

**Demo**:

```
>>> dict((k.lower() if isinstance(k, basestring) else k, v.lower() if isinstance(v, basestring) else v) for k,v in yourDict.iteritems())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
>>> {k.lower() if isinstance(k, str) else k: v.lower() if isinstance(v, str) else v for k,v in yourDict.items()}
>>> {'domain': 'workgroup', 'name': 'ca-ltp-john', 111: 'ok', 'is_adserver': 0, 'is_connectionbroker': 0, 'domain_pingable': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3, divided the problem in two functions: one to lower the keys of a dictionary and the other for the values:

```py
def keys_to_lower(d: dict) -> dict:
    return {k.lower(): keys_to_lower(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v for k, v in d.items()}


def values_to_lower(d: dict) -> dict:
    def to_lower(v):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            return values_to_lower(v)
        elif isinstance(v, str):
            return v.lower()
        return v
    return {k: to_lower(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Then if you want both (keys and values) to `lower()`:

```py
keys_to_lower(values_to_lower({
    'ONE': 1,
    'Two': 'TWO',
    'THREE': {
        'FOUR': 4
    },
    'FIVE': ['Five']
}))
```